# Get Request Headers Always nil in staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to get request header with key `HTTP_X_UID`, I can get it in development environment with this

```
request.env['HTTP_X_UID']
```

or

```
request.headers['HTTP_X_UID']
```

or

```
request.headers.env["HTTP_X_UID"]
```

But in staging environment I can't get it.

Note: 
I'm using nginx in staging

Comment: how are u sending the header in the request?
is it `x_uid` or `x-uid`?
sometimes `x_uid` work in dev env but not in other in enviornments

Comment: @NimishGupta I'm use `x_uid`, but I try with `x-uid` and it's work now. can you write that as answer and explain with reference about that? I will accept your answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to use `x-uid` instead of `x_uid`.

Header names must be separated by `-` as per convention.

There is some strange behavior because of which it works in dev environment.

Hope this helps.